# The span tag inside the h6 tag is not printing the record

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I am making the clone of instagram. In the following code , the span tag is not printing the name of the user who has commented on the post ,. I have checked the record by consoling the result  , record is having the name and all the data required . The record.text is working properly and is showing the text but I also want to show the name of the person who commented and it is not working .

```
{
   
                                   item.comments.map(record=>{
                                       return(
                                       <h6 key={record._id}><span style={{fontWeight:"500"}}>{record.postedBy.name}</span> {record.text}</h6>
                                       )
                                   })
                                   
}
```

Following file is in main concern:-

Home.js :-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { UserContext } from '../../App';
const Home = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext)
    useEffect(() => {

        fetch('/allpost', {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt")
            }
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)
                setData(result.posts)
            })

    }, [])

    const likePost = (id) => {

        fetch('/like', {
            method: "put",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt")
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                postId: id
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                //console.log(result)
                const newData = data.map(item => {
                    if (item._id == result._id) {
                        return result
                    } else {
                        return item
                    }
                })
                setData(newData)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }


    const unlikePost = (id) => {

        fetch('/unlike', {
            method: "put",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt")
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                postId: id
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                //console.log(result)

                const newData = data.map(item => {
                    if (item._id == result._id) {
                        return result
                    } else {
                        return item
                    }
                })
                setData(newData)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })

    }

    const makeComment = (text, postId) => {
        fetch('/comment', {

            method: "put",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("jwt")
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                postId,
                text
            })
        }).then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {

                console.log(result)
                const newData = data.map(item => {
                    if (item._id == result._id) {
                        return result
                    } else {
                        return item
                    }

                })
                setData(newData)
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
    }

    return (
        <div className="home">

            {
                data.map(item => {

                    return (

                        <div className="card home-card">
                            <h5>{item.postedBy.name}</h5>
                            <div className="card-image">
                                <img src={item.photo} />
                                <div className="card-content">
                                    {item.likes.includes(state._id)
                                        ?
                                        <i className="material-icons"
                                            onClick={() => { unlikePost(item._id) }}>
                                            thumb_down
                                         </i>
                                        :
                                        <i className="material-icons"
                                            onClick={() => { likePost(item._id) }}>
                                            thumb_up
                                        </i>
                                    }
                                    <i className="material-icons" style={{ color: "Red" }}>favorite</i>
                                    <h6>
                                        {item.likes.length} likes
                                    </h6>
                                    <h6>
                                        {item.title}
                                    </h6>
                                    <p>{item.body}</p>

                                    {
                                    item.comments.map(record=>{
                                        return(
                                        <h6 key={record._id}><span style={{fontWeight:"500"}}>{record.postedBy.name}</span> {record.text}</h6>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }

                                    <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                                        e.preventDefault()
                                        // console.log(e.target[0].value)
                                        makeComment(e.target[0].value, item._id)
                                    }}>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="add a comment" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    )
                })
            }
        </div>

    )

}
export default Home
```

Comment: You should `console.log(record);` to see what the object looks like.  Probably a typo.

Comment: There is no typo. This is the information stored in postedBy array along with _id  :-   name: "neeta"

Comment: Please add the console output to your question. I am confused whether it is record._id or record.postedBy._id